# Fail to exclude words from grep command

Tags: linux, bash, grep

For filtering errors in log files I have a command something like that

```
sudo grep -R --color=always -ri "err" *.log | grep -v "terry"
```

but the output isn't what I want. I still see lines like

> mail.log:Mar 27 10:31:44 (removed) postfix/smtp[5449]: 4EB0822348: to=, relay=(removed), delay=6.6, delays=0.55/0.02/3.4/2.6, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 OK id=1csFlH-00010k-6T)

Why is that line here when I have excluded "terry" from it?

Comment: What platform? Windows? Please provide an example of input. Make sure that `\n` is obvious

Comment: ubuntu 16.10  - to reproduce, paste the above mail.log line into a mail.log file and run the above grep command ... it should not display it

Answer (score 3):

Your "--color=always" is why you are still getting the the result. Remember that the pipe sends the stdout of one program to stdin of another. The output of your first grep command is outputting colors. In order to output color to the screen you have to send the color codes to the shell. In order for the shell to interpret these characters as colors it must use escape codes like this:

```
echo -e "This is \e[31mRed"
```

The word "Red" will be red when it is echo'ed. So grep is sending the escape characters to the second grep command. Go ahead and try it for yourself by redirecting your first grep command to a file and then examining the file.

```
grep -R --color=always -ri 'err' /tmp/log/syslog > /tmp/log/syslog2
```

Now open the file in a text editor (Don't cat the file out as you will just see the colors).

```
ar 26 10:30:59 zipmaster07 cinnamon-screensaver-dialog: pam_ecryptfs: seteuid ^[[01;31m^[[Kerr^[[m^[[Kor
Mar 26 14:27:19 zipmaster07 cinnamon-screensaver-dialog: pam_ecryptfs: seteuid ^[[01;31m^[[Kerr^[[m^[[Kor
t^[[01;31m^[[Kerr^[[m^[[Ky was here with an ^[[01;31m^[[Kerr^[[m^[[Kor.
mail.log:Mar 27 10:31:44 (removed) postfix/smtp[5449]: 4EB0822348: to=<t^[[01;31m^[[Kerr^[[m^[[Ky@(removed
```

The line "terry@...." is not terry anymore it is "t^[[01;31m^[[Kerr^...." and an inverted match of "terry" is not equal to "t^[[01;31m^[[Kerr^....", therefore grep includes it.

You need to remove the color option.

```
jschaeffer@zipmaster07 ~ $ grep -R -ri 'err' /tmp/log/sys2.log
pam_ecryptfs: seteuid err
pam_ecryptfs: seteuid err
terry was here with an error.
mail.log:Mar 27 10:31:44 (removed) postfix/smtp[5449]: 4EB0822348: to=<terry@(removed)>, relay=(removed), delay=6.6, delays=0.55/0.02/3.4/2.6, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 OK id=1csFlH-00010k-6T)
```

Now with the second grep.

```
schaeffer@zipmaster07 ~ $ grep -R -ri 'err' /tmp/log/sys2.log | grep -v terry
pam_ecryptfs: seteuid err
pam_ecryptfs: seteuid err
```

Hopefully this all make sense.

Comment: ah, those color values, make sense! thanks for pointing to these.

Comment: but ... i still want to highlight the matches with colors. otherwise it will be too painful for my eyes to scan so many log lines. is there any trick to make it work with `--color=always` together?

Comment: I'm sure there is single regex that can be written that will include "err" but not "terry", I just can't come up with it right now. With a single regex you can use a single grep command. In the meantime, just flip the grep statements:

`grep -v terry /tmp/log/sys2.log | grep -i --color=always 'err'`

Comment: hmmm, there is a new problem when it comes to recursion:

`grep -v terry -R /tmp/log/*.log | grep -i --color=always 'err'`

does not seem to be recursive and still shows only those entries in the first folder.

Comment: The recursive option doesn't work because you are not specifying a directory (unless any of your entries under /tmp/log that end in .log are an actual directory instead of files). There is no directories to recurse in the first place. What you mean is: `grep -vi terry -R /tmp/log --include '*.log' | grep -i --color=always 'err'`. Please read the man page: grep(1).